# How to use multiple CSS classes with MUI 5 SX prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know how to use multiple CSS classes with MUI 5 SX prop? I created a base class that I want to use with my Box components but use a second class specifically for the text inside of the Box. Applying base class, such as `sx={styles.baseBoxStyle}` works but `sx={styles.baseBoxStyle styles.customBoxFontStyle}` returns an error. Full code snippet and sandbox provided below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-styling-uqt9m?file=/pages/index.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

const styles = {
  baseBoxStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    borderRadius: "20px 20px 20px 20px",
    border: "1px solid black",
    maxWidth: "150px",
    margin: "20px",
    padding: "10px"
  },
  customBoxFontStyle: {
    color: "yellow",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
};

export default function Index() {
  return <Box sx={styles.baseBoxStyle styles.customBoxFontStyle}>This is a test</Box>;
}
```

Comment: Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-styling-uqt9m?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Hi, if I want to use theme in styles and pass it, how can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) as its commonly used library, or you can just make string from these styles that you pass into sx `sx={styles.baseBoxStyle+' '+styles.customBoxFontStyle}`

Comment: I just now tried the suggested on sx prop but it doesn't work as they are objects. https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-styling-uqt9m?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: oh sorry, i dont know why i thought, these are classes... but there you can try to combine these two objects: `sx={{...styles.baseBoxStyle,...styles.customBoxFontStyle}}`

Comment: Sorry Wraithy, that doesn't work either.

Comment: my apologizes. Your solution does indeed work. I confirmed this after consulting with another React developer who suggested the same. Not sure why it didn't work initially tested but I suspect I neglected to wrap it in additional curly brackets.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem and came up with this solution.

```
  <Box sx={[styles.baseBoxStyle, styles.customBoxFontStyle]}>
    This is a test
  </Box>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-blackwell-oqp9ph?file=/src/App.js:416-517

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 11):

If you want combine 2 calsses, and you get one of them as props you should work like this

```js
const componnent = (styles) => {
 return ( 
  <ListItem
    sx={[
      {
        width: 'auto',
        textDecoration: 'underline',
      },
      ...(Array.isArray(styles) ? styles : [styles]),
    ]}
  /> 
 )
}
```

You cannot spread `sx` directly because `SxProps` (typeof sx) can be an array

Answer (score 5):

For a simple solution, can deconstruct the style objects and compile into one object.

`<Box sx={{...styles.baseBoxStyle,...styles.customBoxFontStyle}}>This is a test</Box>`

Answer (score 2):

With the following functions

```
import { SxProps, Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const withSxProp = (
    sxProp: SxProps<Theme> | undefined,
    other: SxProps<Theme>
): SxProps<Theme> => {
    if (!sxProp) {
        return other;
    } else {
        return mergeSx(sxProp, other);
    }
};

export const mergeSx = (...sxProps: SxProps<Theme>[]): SxProps<Theme> => {
    return sxProps.reduce((prev, currentValue) => {
        return [
            ...(Array.isArray(prev) ? prev : [prev]),
            ...(Array.isArray(currentValue) ? currentValue : [currentValue]),
        ];
    }, [] as SxProps<Theme>);
};
```

Usage

```
class MyComponent = (parentSxProp: SxProps<Theme>) => {
    const sxChildDefault = {
       display: "flex"
    }
    const innerSx1 = {
        display: "flex"
    }
    const innerSx2 = {
        flexDirection: "column"
    }
    return <Box
       sx={withSxProp(parentSxProp, sxChildDefault)}
    >
        <Box
            sx={mergeSx(innerSx1, innerSx2)}
        />
    </Box>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on Aleksander's answer, there is a section about merging `sx` in [MUI official documentation](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#passing-the-sx-prop).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import FormLabel from '@mui/material/FormLabel';
import { SxProps, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

interface ListHeaderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
}

function ListHeader({ sx = [], children }: ListHeaderProps) {
  return (
    <ListItem
      sx={[
        {
          width: 'auto',
          textDecoration: 'underline',
        },
        // You cannot spread `sx` directly because `SxProps` (typeof sx) can be an array.
        ...(Array.isArray(sx) ? sx : [sx]),
      ]}
    >
      <FormLabel sx={{ color: 'inherit' }}>{children}</FormLabel>
    </ListItem>
  );
}

export default function PassingSxProp() {
  return (
    <ListHeader
      sx={(theme) => ({
        color: 'info.main',
        ...theme.typography.overline,
      })}
    >
      Header
    </ListHeader>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant use `sx` with classes. I have not seen any example in [documentation](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/).

Comment: In this context I'm referring to JSS as classes, not traditional CSS class. In the example I provided in this post, sx={styles.baseBoxStyle} works without issue.

Comment: I see. `styles.baseBoxStyle` is js object. It pretends just temporary constant. In these cases making a new object by destruction will work.
I was confused you try to do similar way as `makeStyles` does.

Comment: I'm migrating from v4 to v5 and because I used makeStyles in v4, which is deprecated in v5, my goal was to not have to reformat all of my styling.

Comment: Yeap. I am new to MUI. I have the same problem. All examples I find a references point are made with `makeStyles` in v4. I can use the legacy method for my works, it works but I am trying to figure out how should styles components in v5 way.